# C++11 - drop input from stream

Tags: c++, c++11, io, cin

When I have a program that may take up to `n` lines of input to solve a problem before starting with the next, I need to throw away all lines of input that belong to the old problem when the program can solve it before having read all the input.

I could, of course, simply loop until I reach the new problem's input, but reading and storing all that data may be expensive. Is there no way to simply tell the input stream to ignore the next so-and-so-many values?

Comment: Please add an example input. If there's some kind of separating character between two problems, you could use [`std::basic_istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void discardLines(std::istream &in, std::size_t count)
{
    if (!in)  
       return;

    for (auto i = count; i != 0; --i)
         in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

and call it with any `istream` type like `cin`, `ifstream` and `istringstream`.

[Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) for `std::basic_istream::ignore`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. I think it's worth mentioning that when you have a couple integers in a line and you read all of them, the corresponding ``\n`` is *not* read. (Which in my case meant I had to use ``i++`` instead of the ``++i`` I expected.)

Comment: @User1291 Does it? I mean, there was a mistake in the `for` because I wrote (`count != 0` instead of `i != 0`). Can you show what you mean with an example on some online compiler?

Comment: Of course. Will this do? https://ideone.com/zmRw0V# Btw, it seems numeric_limits isn't part of the std but requires the inclusion of <limits>

Comment: Yes, it's in `limits`. The issue with the newline is that `ignore` is an UnformattedInput function, that is a `\n` is considered an actual character (unformatted functions -`cin.get()` etc.- will read it) whilst functions that deal with formatted input won't, like `cin >> myChar`. That's why mixing formatted and unformatted input isn't advisable.